# Correct usage of DataWriter?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

In an UWP app, I'm experiencing problems with the usage of [DataWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208154). When I deploy the UWP app to an ARM machine (RaspBerry PI 2B) it only occasionally succeeds to write a string to the serialdevice. Find my code below. Note: this function only gets called every 30 seconds or so.

```
        public async Task Transmit(string command)
        {
          if (serialPort == null)
            serialPort = await GetSerialDeviceAsync();

          dataWriter = new DataWriter(serialPort.OutputStream);

          dataWriter.WriteString(command);

          await dataWriter.StoreAsync();

          await dataWriter.FlushAsync();

          dataWriter.DetachStream();

          dataWriter.Dispose();  
        }
```

I have two questions:

Can someone confirm that I'm using the correct approach of DataWriter?

If I would want to reuse the dataWriter instead of defining a new DataWriter() every time, should I Flush and Detach the stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are using DataWriter correctly. I would recommend that you continue to dispose of the DataWriter each time instead of re using it. You should also be using the using statement instead of Dispose() e.g.:

```
using (var dataWriter = new DataWriter(serialPort.OutputStream))
{
...
}
```

This accomplishes the same thing as placing Dispose() within the finally block of a try catch finally.